# How do I extract only certain email addresses from a body of text has many?

Tags: regex

There are a number of email addresses, sent along with their roles, in an url encoded json. Like so:

```
hl=en_US&token=AFNOsBbXXvng6zJmmPyIlya1dT48RKqmaQ%3A1441100947178&foreignService=explorer&shareService=explorer&authuser=0&locale=en_US&requestType=aclChange&itemIds=0B-i4kCZeNb05Y3FrVXFLYU41N0U&confirmed=false&modelChanges=%7B%22aclEntries%22%3A%5B%7B%22scope%22%3A%7B%22scopeType%22%3A%22user%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22babar.memon%40gmail.com%22%2C%22id%22%3A%22112542596153041291285%22%2C%22me%22%3Afalse%2C%22requiresKey%22%3Afalse%2C%22email%22%3A%22babar.memon%40gmail.co%22%7D%2C%22role%22%3A30%7D%2C%7B%22scope%22%3A%7B%22iconUrl%22%3A%22%2Fc%2Fu%2F0%2Fphotos%2Fpublic%2FAIbEiAIAAABDCL_k77OCsqvJPSILdmNhcmRfcGhvdG8qKGM0MmEwMjBkZWQ0MDAzMzMwYjI2MjczZmNlZWVlMDA3NDUxMGI2N2MwAdau5OHbez_zFcRyTELkBcRF-Lv9%22%2C%22scopeType%22%3A%22user%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22Saad%20Rehman%22%2C%22id%22%3A%22104436799417545912895%22%2C%22me%22%3Afalse%2C%22requiresKey%22%3Afalse%2C%22email%22%3A%22this.saad%40gmail.com%22%7D%2C%22role%22%3A20%7D%2C%7B%22scope%22%3A%7B%22iconUrl%22%3A%22%2Fc%2Fu%2F0%2Fphotos%2Fpublic%2FAIbEiAIAAABDCL_k77OCsqvJPSILdmNhcmRfcGhvdG8qKGM0MmEwMjBkZWQ0MDAzMzMwYjI2MjczZmNlZWVlMDA3NDUxMGI2N2MwAdau5OHbez_zFcRyTELkBcRF-Lv9%22%2C%22scopeType%22%3A%22user%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22Saad%20Rehman%22%2C%22id%22%3A%22104436799417545912895%22%2C%22me%22%3Afalse%2C%22requiresKey%22%3Afalse%2C%22email%22%3A%22this.saad%40gmail.com%22%7D%2C%22role%22%3A60%7D%2C%7B%22scope%22%3A%7B%22scopeType%22%3A%22user%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22Asim%20Kazmi%22%2C%22id%22%3A%22118161687853857289891%22%2C%22me%22%3Afalse%2C%22requiresKey%22%3Afalse%2C%22email%22%3A%22asim.kazmi%40elasticaqa.info%22%7D%2C%22role%22%3A20%7D%2C%7B%22scope%22%3A%7B%22scopeType%22%3A%22user%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22Asim%20Kazmi%22%2C%22id%22%3A%22118161687853857289891%22%2C%22me%22%3Afalse%2C%22requiresKey%22%3Afalse%2C%22email%22%3A%22asim.kazmi%40elasticaqa.info%22%7D%2C%22role%22%3A60%7D%5D%7D
```

What if I only want the email addresses that have role 30 next to them, or in another rule, all the email addresses that have role 20 next to them.

This is what I have done so far:
`

```
.*?email.22.3A.22([a-zA-Z0-9_.+%-]+?%40[a-zA-Z0-9_%-]+?[.][a-zA-Z0-9_.%-]+?).22[^r]+role.22.3A30.7D
```

This is supposed to give me all the email addresses that have role 30 next to them i.e. babar.memon%40elastica.com. If I put `.0` in place of `30`, then I get all the email addresses, just like how I want them, except that I want them separately, first all the ones that have role 30, then role 20 etc.

This regex can be found in action here https://regex101.com/r/rW0qO9/1

Comment: The given regex works for the given text, but this is just an example that works because the very first email has role 30, we can see it breaks if we try the regex with role 60 etc.

Comment: Why don't you split the query string and unescape the percent encoding? Writing regex for this is insane

Comment: All I am getting is the url encoded text, which I can't decode to put in json. Also, our system uses a propriety language which is parsed by a propriety 'compiler'. A lot of limitations.

Comment: Does your system allow you to write code to process this?

Comment: Nope, it has to be done via regex

Comment: Without code I'd say this can't be done. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regular expression
`.*?email.22.3A.22([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+?%40[a-zA-Z0-9_%-]+?[.][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+).22[^r]+role.22.3A(20).7D`
, I have slightly changed the capturing group since in email address we cannot have special character like %, so it will be only appearing when '@' is encoded  as %40

Comment: that use of `.` is high dangerous.  Cannot recommend it, even if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Regex can be use to extract the pattern from string, you can't extract them in specific order since each match is a sub-string of sample string. You have to collect these matches and order them in the later stage.

Also there is a possibility that you construct your regex dynamically by parameterizing the `(.0)` part (in your regex) with `20` and `30` and `40` by taking a variable and extract each of them one by one.